# Python static class member: access via instance

Tags: python, class, oop, static-members

I have a class:

```
class A:
  x = 12
```

What is the difference between these two access forms to the static member?:

```
a = A()
print(a.x)  # >> 12
print(a.__class__.x) # >> 12
```

Comment: In this situation none, but you can shadow the class-namespace with assignment directly to an instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference when getting the value; `a.x` will fall back to `A.x` (which is the same as `a.__class__.x`).

However if you try to set a value, `a.x = 13` will set a new instance variable, leaving `A.x` with the original value. From then on, `a.x` will always find the instance value not the class one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, they are the same. This is related to how python **lookup it's attributes.**

It first looks at the **instance** attributes, if it doesn't find it it looks in the **class** attributes, and so forth.

In the second statement (`a.__class__.x`) you explicity tells python to look straight in the class dict, skipping the instance lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `a.x` returns the variable value of instance of the class (scope limited to the class object) whereas `A.x` returns the value of class variable. You may verify it like:

```
# create object of class A()
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()

# same value
>>> A.x   
12
>>> a.x
12

# updated a.x
>>> a.x = 5
>>> A.x   # still old value
12
>>> a.x   # new value
5
>>> b.x    # old value
12

# updated A.x
>>> A.x = 9  # new value
>>> A.x
9
>>> a.x   # old value
5
>>> b.x  # new value
9
```

**Conclusion**: If you update the value of instance of the class, the change will be restricted to that instance. However if you change the value of class variable, the change will be reflected to all the instances if the instance don't have overridden the value explicitly.